# UI Upgrade 2010 to 2013

Tags: upgrade, feature-upgrade, migrate

When I´m migrating my SharePoint 2010 portal to 2013 an executing the "Upgrade to 2013 UI" I´m getting the following error:

```
Upgrade SPFeatureDefinition aj2bj   INFO    SPSite Url=https://www.myurl.de d4bc8e9d-18d2-70fd-6e73-c15044422beb                                                            
Upgrade SPFeatureDefinition aj2bj   ERROR   Feature upgrade action 'AddContentTypeField' threw an exception upgrading Feature 'CTypes' (Id: 15/'695b6570-a48b-4a8e-8ea5-26e a7fc1d162') in Site 'https://www.myurl.de': <nativehr>0x80070002</nativehr><na  tivestack></nativestack>There is no Web named "/allgemein/cmngemanagement". <nativehr>0x80070002</nativehr><nativesta   ck></nativestack>There is no Web named "/allgemein/cmngemanagement".    <nativehr>0x80070002</nativehr> <nativestack></nativestack>There is no  Web named"/allgemein/cmngemanagement".  d4bc8e9d-18d2-70fd-6e73-c15044422beb
Upgrade SPSiteWssSequence2  ajy6m   INFO    SPSite Url=https://www.myurl.de d4bc8e9d-18d2-70fd-6e73-c15044422beb                                                            
Upgrade SPSiteWssSequence2  ajy6m   ERROR   Feature upgrade incomplete for Feature 'CTypes' (Id: 15/'695b6570-a48b-4a8e-8ea5-26ea7fc1d162') in Site 'https://www.myurl.de'. Exception: <nativehr>0x80070002</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>There is   no Web named "/allgemein/cmngemanagement". <nativehr>0x80070002</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>There is no Web    named "/allgemein/cmngemanagement". <nativehr>0x80070002</nativehr> <nativestack></nativestack>There is no Web named"/allgemein/cmn gemanagement".  d4bc8e9d-18d2-70fd-6e73-c1504   4422beb
Upgrade SPManager       ajxoe   INFO    No context object       d4bc8e9d-18d2-70fd-6e73-c15044422beb                                                            
Upgrade SPManager       ajxoe   ERROR   RunUpgradeSiteSession [SPSite Url=https://www.myurl.de] failed. d4bc8e9d-18d2-70fd-6e73-c15044422beb                                                            
Upgrade SPManager       ajxoe   INFO    No context object       d4bc8e9d-18d2-70fd-6e73-c15044422beb                                                            
Upgrade SPManager       ajxoe   ERROR   Exception: Upgrade completed with errors.  Review the upgrade log file located in D:\Logs\ULS\SiteUpgrade-20160711-130339-569.log.  The number of errors and warnings is listed at the end of the upgrade log file. d4bc8e9d-18d2-70fd-6e73-c15044422beb                                                    
Upgrade SPManager       ajxoe   INFO    No context object       d4bc8e9d-18d2-70fd-6e73-c15044422beb                                                            
Upgrade SPManager       ajxoe   ERROR   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.CheckPoint()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSiteSession.CheckPoint() at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPManager.RunUpgradeSiteSessionCore(Object  lockObject, SPSite site, SPUpgradeOperationFlags upgradeOperationFlags, Boolean checkConcurrentSiteUpgradeSession)  d4bc8e9d-18d2-70fd-6e73-c15044422beb
```

And yes the site is not existing.

Any ideas to solve this error?

Comment: Do you have a custom site definition in your SP2010 environment?

Comment: Yes. There are.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have custom Site Definitions in your 2010 environment, you need to address these first. Especially if you plan to use them in your 2013 environment.

> First step in porting the custom site definitions to SharePoint 2013 is to identify what site definitions will cause the upgrade to fail and prevent the self service site collection upgrade. Unless you manage to complete at least one test upgrade you can’t really understand what customizations need further tweaking to make it work in 2013 version. During your first test migration review the error log to make a list of all the custom site definitions that prevents migration. Once you have this list of all the site definitions and respective WSP packages, go to your 2010 environment and download those WSP files. These WSP packages are either deployed at the site collection level or at the farm level. Once you have the list of WSP files it’s time to make those declarative changes required for SharePoint 2013.

You could try deploying the WSP's as is, and see what result you get. I have encountered both a successful implementation just deploying the WSP, and failures. If it fails, you need to build new 2013-specific WSP package like Karthik Murugesan explains in his blog-post [Migrating Custom Site Definitions & Web Templates during SharePoint 2013 Upgrade. It's a dirty job but you gotta to do it!](http://www.siteactions.net/2013/11/10/migrating-custom-site-definitions-web-templates-during-sharepoint-2013-upgrade-its-a-dirty-job-but-you-gotta-to-do-it/)

> ## Follow these steps to start updating your WSP file to make the site definition 2013 ready.
>
> 1. Open Visual Studio and create a New Project
> 2. In the list of available templates select SharePoint 2013 – Import Solution Package. Click OK.
> 3. Make sure the project name is same as the 2010 WSP file name so it is easy to reference it later during the upgrade
> 4. In the next section choose one of the WSP files exported from 2010 environment
> 5. In Solution Explorer, find the Onet.xml file in your project and open it
> 6. In SharePoint 2013 custom master page references are set to the default master page named seattle.master. If the default master page in SharePoint 2010 is customized, change the reference to that custom page in Onet.xml
> 7. If you review one of the existing site templates you’ll notice there are certain set of Features included in the template. Optionally you can make sure the following set of Features are included in the WebFeatures section

```
Feature Name            Feature ID
AccSvcAddAccessApp      d2b9ec23-526b-42c5-87b6-852bd83e0364
AnnouncementsList       00bfea71-d1ce-42de-9c63-a44004ce0104
BaseWeb                 99fe402e-89a0-45aa-9163-85342e865dc8
BizAppsListTemplates    065c78be-5231-477e-a972-14177cc5b3c7
ContactsList            00bfea71-7e6d-4186-9ba8-c047ac750105
ContactsList            00bfea71-7e6d-4186-9ba8-c047ac750105
CustomList              00bfea71-de22-43b2-a848-c05709900100
DataConnectionLibrary   00bfea71-dbd7-4f72-b8cb-da7ac0440130
DataSourceLibrary       00bfea71-f381-423d-b9d1-da7a54c50110
DiscussionsList         00bfea71-6a49-43fa-b535-d15c05500108
DocumentLibrary         00bfea71-e717-4e80-aa17-d0c71b360101
EventsList              00bfea71-ec85-4903-972d-ebe475780106
EventsList              00bfea71-ec85-4903-972d-ebe475780106
ExternalList            00bfea71-9549-43f8-b978-e47e54a10600
FollowingContent        a7a2793e-67cd-4dc1-9fd0-43f61581207a
GanttTasksList          00bfea71-513d-4ca0-96c2-6a47775c0119
GettingStarted          4aec7207-0d02-4f4f-aa07-b370199cd0c7
GridList                00bfea71-3a1d-41d3-a0ee-651d11570120
HierarchyTasksList      f9ce21f8-f437-4f7e-8bc6-946378c850f0
IPFSWebFeatures         f9ce21f8-f437-4f7e-8bc6-946378c850f0
IssuesList              00bfea71-5932-4f9c-ad71-1557e5751100
LinksList               00bfea71-5932-4f9c-ad71-1557e5751100
MBrowserRedirect        d95c97f3-e528-4da2-ae9f-32b3535fbb59
MDSFeature              87294c72-f260-42f3-a41b-981a2ffce37a
MobilityRedirect        f41cc668-37e5-4743-b4a8-74d1db3fd8a4
MySiteMicroBlog         ea23650b-0340-4708-b465-441a41c37af7
NoCodeWorkflowLibrary   00bfea71-f600-43f6-a895-40c0de7b0117
PictureLibrary          00bfea71-52d4-45b3-b544-b1c71b620109
PremiumWeb              0806d127-06e6-447a-980e-2e90b03101b8
PromotedLinksList       192efa95-e50c-475e-87ab-361cede5dd7f
ReportListTemplate      2510d73f-7109-4ccc-8a1c-314894deeb3a
SiteFeed                15a572c6-e545-4d32-897a-bab6f5846e18
SiteFeedController      5153156a-63af-4fac-b557-91bd8c315432
SurveysList             00bfea71-eb8a-40b1-80c7-506be7590102
TaskListNewsFeed        ff13819a-a9ac-46fb-8163-9d53357ef98d
TasksList               00bfea71-a83e-497e-9ba0-7a5c597d0107
TeamCollab              00bfea71-4ea5-48d4-a4ad-7ea5c011abe5
WebPageLibrary          00bfea71-c796-4402-9f2f-0eb9a6e71b18
WikiPageHomePage        00bfea71-d8fe-4fec-8dad-01c19a6e4053
WorkflowHistoryList     00bfea71-4ea5-48d4-a4ad-305cf7030140
workflowProcessList     00bfea71-2d77-4a75-9fca-76516689e21a
WorkflowServiceStore    2c63df2b-ceab-42c6-aeff-b3968162d4b1
WorkflowTask            57311b7a-9afd-4ff0-866e-9393ad6647b1
XmlFormLibrary          00bfea71-1e1d-4562-b56a-f05371bb0115
```

> 8. Now you are ready to generate the WSP file. After compiling the project file Deploy the solution. Chances are the deployment will fail if you haven’t associated a valid SharePoint farm to the project. You can safely ignore that and go to the bin folder to get your WSP file.
> 9. Upload and Deploy the WSP file in your SharePoint 2013 test environment and try the upgrade again.

Comment: I'm not following how a custom site definition is going to cause errors about sites that don't exist.  I'm experiencing the same error as OP and everything confirms that the webs simply don't exist and were deleted long before migration.

Comment: @Jack Me neither, but it does. Maybe it's due to the fact that you can restore a deleted site, and that it exists in the database. Check by running PS Script Get-SPDeletedSite. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh286316.aspx

Comment: Or possibly second stage recycle bin in the case of missing webs.  I'll check there and report.  currently fighting a content type upgrade error, when there's no reference to which content type is actually the issue.  Fun with maintenance and upgrades. :)